# Compositional SMILES data

Tags: smiles

I am interested to know if it is possible to encode compositional information in SMILES strings or other structural identifiers.

For instance, in generating a SMILES string when combining two molecules, C$_{14}$H$_{10}$ and C$_{18}$H$_{12}$, I am wondering if it is possible to specify the composition of the different constituents [e.g. (C$_{14}$H$_{10}$)$_{0.4}$(C$_{18}$H$_{12}$)$_{0.6}$]. The goal would be to generate unique SMILES strings for this compound molecule as the composition sweeps from x=: 0 to 1 as (C$_{14}$H$_{10}$)$_{x}$(C$_{18}$H$_{12}$)$_{(1-x)}$. I am hoping this is a discrete method, such as 5 SMILES strings as x=: 0, 0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 1, etc...

Is there a way to generate a "canonical SMILES string" for such compound molecules with varying stoichiometry? I read that even toluene has 7 possible SMILES strings so I could imagine compositional information is not possible to encode in a structural notation.

If such a thing does not exist, would it be feasible or make sense to try and create a new type of structural notation for "novel compounds" that do not have entries in chemical databases?

Please let me know if structural identifiers is not the right path!

Comment: Would that be truly a compound, or just a mixture? I think, to make a true compound, it would be necessary to break or make bonds. There are numerous sites where bonds can be created/broken in large compounds, and I think without this information it's not possible to assign a SMILES string.

Comment: There are canonical SMILES (whichever toolkit you use should have a method to generate a canonical SMILES). But if you're generating mixtures, I think you want a different representation, something like: `[smiles1, fraction1, smiles2, fraction2]` with some code to ensure a unique ordering between the SMILES (e.g., alphabetical order of the canonical SMILES)

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago, but I wonder if there's any update you can give us after all these months? Also, are you still actively in need of an answer to this question? Were the comments by @ksousa and Geoff helpful?

Comment: edit update!: Yes! @NikeDattani, both ksousa and Geoff Hutchison were very helpful. I ended up finding this article, [link](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-018-2523-5) that talked about doing something similar to what I was looking for in literature. As for implementing my mixture-based SMILES data, the project I was working on shifted a bit and ended up not needing this information in lieu of broader categorical definitions of our chemical inputs.